# Example of Reverse KL Divergence in Supervised Learning

Tags: loss-function, supervised-learning, implementation, code

It is of common knowledge that Supervised Learning uses forward KL divergence. However, I would like to use Reverse KL Divergence and am looking for examples of similar usage in literature. Most importantly, I would like to see how it is implemented.
If it is not feasible to implement it, I would also like to know the difficulties and approximations or workarounds to do the same.

Comment: Reverse KL simply switch the two operands, so you can use any implementation of KL divergence but switch the inputs.

Comment: Can you prove that it will work? @AdamOudad